# Multiple service directory in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

So im wondering if its possible to run a multiple sub directories with my current config of nginx. I would like to have the directories as www.hostname.org/service1 www.hostname.org/service2 is this achievable ? This is my nginx.conf

```
server {
# Update this line to be your domain
server_name www.hostname.org;

# Ensure these lines point to your SSL certificate and key
# ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
# ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
# Use these lines instead if you created a self-signed certificate
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www_hostname_org_ee.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/hostname.key;

# Ensure this line points to your dhparams file
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;


# These shouldn't need to be changed
listen [::]:32776 default_server ipv6only=off; # if your nginx version is >= 1.9.5 you can also add the "http2" flag here
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";
ssl on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

proxy_buffering off;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.8:8123;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are service1 and service2 in the same directory? (like /var/www/services/service1 and /var/www/services/service2) Which type of services are?. Probably what you need is to change the root depending on the location.

Comment: They are on different IPs im basically using it as a reverse proxy.

Comment: yeah, it is possible, the location you are using is for everything, just slit it in different ones for each service. I will suppose they are in different ips in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ ^/service1 {
    proxy_pass http://ipforservice1:8123;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}

location ~ ^/service2 {
    proxy_pass http://ipforservice2:8123;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

Is this what you wanted? Go to different ips for different services?